# iPhone object checking to release

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, release

I want to check if an object has some count or not Here is my testing code

```
NSMutableArray  *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if(array)
    {
        NSLog(@"hiiiiiii"); 
    }
```

CASE-2

```
NSMutableArray  *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array release];
    if(array)
    {
        NSLog(@"hiiiiiii"); 
    }
```

Here in both cases i got same output as printed "hiiiiiii".

Can anyone tell me how will i check if my object need to release or already released.

I know that i should have track of my object's counters but i am at a stage where my code is too much complexed and i need help..

Please help..

ALso tell that how much memory leak is allowed by apple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to check if you "should" release an object. Doing something like "if(object)" only checks the **pointer** to the object. It will return true even if the object it was pointing to was destroyed a long time ago. This is what happens in your second case. The object is destroyed when you call release, but the pointer is still pointing at something, so it returns true. It will only return false if the pointer is set to nil.

However, there is a simple set of rules for calling release. If you ever call "alloc", "new", "copy", "mutableCopy" or "retain" on object, you must **always** call "release" or "autorelease" on it. That will prevent any memory leaks.

Apple does not have a publicized amount of memory leaks allowed. It is always safest to eliminate any known memory leaks; plus, it will mean better performance for your customers.

Comment: Thank You for the answer, upvote will be given when reached to 15 reputation

Comment: So should i use array=nil; everyTime when i release my object...will that be ok....and what about other counts then(if my object has more that 1 count).

Comment: Your object count should only be greater than zero if something else retained it. In that case, they now "own" it and you don't have to worry about it, if they handle it properly (according to the rules) it will be destroyed when all objects are done with it. Yes, it is always safest to set a variable to nil after releasing it.

Answer (score 4):

In your second case you are releasing the NSMutableArray but still it store a **non zero** value although it's no longer for use (To call function OR fetch value).That the reason your `if`  condition got `true`.

Just remember whenever you call `release` on any object, Do'nt forget to assign `nil` to that, So your second code should look like below.

**CASE-2**

```
NSMutableArray  *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array release];
     array = nil;
    if(array)
    {
        NSLog(@"hiiiiiii"); 
    }
```

There is a simple rule of memory management in Object-C if your **alloced** or **retain** any object you must call release on that,

[Read memory management Guide from Apple.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)

Comment: Thank You for the answer, upvote will be given when reached to 15 reputation